# stop an apt-get upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I was trying to upgrade just a single package, so I typed sudo apt-get upgrade packagename.  (Now I know I'm supposed to use apt-get install for that.)  Now apt-get is upgrading everything in my whole system.  I stopped it with shutdown -h now (hey, it worked) as C-c doesn't seem to work very well.

However apt-get has a memory and now I can't do anything with apt-get such as install without it attempting to continue with a full system upgrade.  How do I get apt-get to just abort the upgrade?

---

When I follow the instructions in the accepted answer as suggested by Itai Ganot, this is what happens:

```
$ sudo apt-get autoclean
[sudo] password for dsw: 
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
dsw@dsw-VirtualBox:~$ cd /var/cache/apt/archives/partial
dsw@dsw-VirtualBox:/var/cache/apt/archives/partial$ ls
dsw@dsw-VirtualBox:/var/cache/apt/archives/partial$ ls -a
.  ..
```

Following the instructions in the message:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

eventually stops.  So the above method does seem to stop the apt-get update eventually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two things you can do in order to cancel the upgrade:

1. Try running the following command:

   ```
   # sudo apt-get autoclean
   ```
2. Emptying /var/cache/apt/archives/partial 
   To do that, open a file manager using the gksudo command, such as:

   ```
   # gksudo nautilus /var/cache/apt/archives/partial
   ```

Delete the files within "partial" but not the folder itself.

Comment: this method did seem to work after apt-get did a few more things; there is no room to give the details in this little box, so I made them another answer; thanks

Comment: Cannot do autoclean.     E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the download directory

Comment: Cannot install gksudo.  E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: Use sudo before the command.